# Truncate a table with multiple list partitions in oracle without having to mention the partition name

Tags: oracle, partition

I have a table with multiple list partitions. I basically want to truncate all the partitions at once without having to mention the partition name. I did try using the plain truncate table tabl_name and it seems to work. I am quite new to partitions in oracle and am not too sure if this is the right way of doing it.

I also know from reading that i can delete multiple partitions using the alter table truncate partition command.

Thanks,
Kavin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, truncating the table truncates all partitions.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TRUNCATE-TABLE.html#GUID-B76E5846-75B5-4876-98EC-439E15E4D8A4

> If table is partitioned, then all partitions or subpartitions, as well as the LOB data and LOB index segments for each partition or subpartition, are truncated.

Note some of the documented side-effects also, such as UNUSABLE indexes being made USABLE.

Comment: Thanks much! I was reading through the oracle docs and might have missed it.

Comment: They are not a quick read for sure, but +1 to you for reading the docs - it is an Oracle superpower that is much neglected.